# Addons failing in 2.79 daily builds, here is the error

Tags: add-on, animation-nodes

Some addons like Cubesurfer and Animation Nodes are failing to initialize in latest Daily Builds of 2.79, can someone tell me how to solve this?

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\3D\BlenderBB\blender-2.79.0_10_12_2017\2.79\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 331, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\jgea\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\cubesurfer\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from cubesurfer import mciso
ImportError: Module use of python35.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

Comment: Upgrade your blender python to 3.6.3 (or at least 3.6.0).

Comment: It's most likely your python version like batFinger said but also, keep in mind that the Daily Builds are often unstable therefor full of bugs, so don't expect everything to work.

Comment: Cubesurfer does not initialize in the regular build (2.79) either. I will try recompiling the .pyx file. Does anybody perchance know how one can find out the python version with which a file was compiled?

Comment: Cubesurfer is working perfectly in 2.79 for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both **Animation Nodes** and **CubeSurfer** are compiled addons and subsequently only work on the operating system and python version they were compiled at.

Prior to blender `2.79.x` (nightly builds now), all blender versions used python `3.5`, thus almost all Animation Nodes and CubeSurfer builds used python `3.5` to compile. Now that blender uses `3.6`, all those builds will fail to work just as you experienced.

### Solution

You will have to compile your own builds using python `3.6` or wait for the developers to release new builds.