# Animation Nodes v2 not working with Blender 2.79

Tags: animation-nodes, error

I installed Animation Nodes v2 and installed it on Blender. The moment I tried to enable it, this popped-up.[image]

Any idea how I can fix this? Is it because Animation Nodes v2 is not "yet" supported in Blender 2.79?

Comment: is it a daily build?

Comment: Nope, the latest and official release of Blender 2.79

Comment: maybe related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96721/addons-failing-in-2-79-daily-builds-here-is-the-error

Comment: I downloaded AN v2 from this link and worked just fine: 
https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases

Comment: You sure you're running it on the official release of Blender 2.79? @BertVdB

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's the official release!

Comment: try installing the visual c++ 2015 library as indicated in the error message

Comment: also check if you have downloaded the Windows release of Animation Nodes

Comment: What python version does this version have?

Comment: No idea bro, @OmarAhmad

Comment: @BouzaziWessim Go to the blender console, it will be written there. It will either be `3.6` or `3.5`, which one is it?

Comment: version 3.5.3, @OmarAhmad

Comment: When I tried installing  this same addon I also couldn't run it (though my error-message looked different), in my case it turned out that there were multiple folders in my Blender/2.79/scripts/addons folder named Animation_something like nodes; when I manually deleted all these folders and installed again it worked fine (the exact location of this folder may differ from system to system, but it  should be listed if you click the little white arrow next to the box you check to turn the addon on)